# Error in running a binary file on ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, file, binary

AM trying to run a binary file on ubuntu terminal but getting following error

cant find trained object detector file "object_detector.svm."

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously this file is missing or the program you are running can not locate it. What I will do:
First check if the file really exists:

find . -name 'object_detector.svm'

or you can try to locate at any other folder. On the extreme search everything as root:

```
find / -name 'object_detector.svm'
```

Also, if you have the source code and not only the binaries, then you can try to locate where this file is calling from. Maybe it's a misconfiguration and you can fix it editing the congig files (if there are any). Try

```
grep -R 'object_detector.svm'
```

If you are lucky enough maybe you spot it.

More data from your side needed for further help.

Comment: yes the object_detector.svm file was missing. But now i have relocated it and its running.

Comment: I m glad that you handled the issue.